# After inheriting CRM-Lead unable to hide or add fields to my Custom module in Openerp

Tags: python, odoo, openerp-7

I have created a new custom module and inherited CRM-LEAD. I'm trying add new fields and hide existing fields.I couldn't do it.Can anyone please tell me how can I do it.
My code is

**`__init__.py`:**

```
import lead
```

**`__openerp__.py`:**

```
{
'name': 'Lead Information',
'version': '0.1',
'category': 'Tools',
'description': """This module is Lead information.""",
'author': 'Nitesh',
'website': '',
'depends': ['crm'],
'init_xml': ['lead_view.xml'],
'update_xml': [],
'demo_xml': [],
'installable': True,
'active': True,
'application': True
}
```

**`lead.py`:**

```
from osv import osv
from osv import fields

class crm_lead(osv.osv):
 _name = 'bala.lead'
 _inherit = 'crm.lead'
 _description = "adding fields to crm.lead"
 _coloumns = {
    'nitesh_lead': fields.char('Nitesh Lead',size=64)
 }
```

**`lead_view.xml`:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
<data>
    <!-- ========================This is Form layout===============================-->
    <record id="crm_case_form_view_leads_extended" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">CRM - Leads Form</field>
        <field name="model">crm.lead</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="crm.crm_case_form_view_leads" />
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <field name="email_from" postion="replace"/>
            <field name="partner_name" postion="after">
                <field name="nitesh_lead"/>
            </field>
       </field>
    </record>
    <record id="new_lead" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name">Lead</field>
        <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
        <field name="res_model">crm.lead</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="view_mode">form</field>
        <field name="view_id" ref="crm_case_form_view_leads_extended"/>
    </record>
       <!-- ===========================Menu Settings=========================== -->
    <menuitem name ="Lead" id = "menu_lis_lab" action="new_lead"/>
</data>
</openerp>
```

Can anyone please say me where did I go wrong?

Comment: want to hide all the exisitng fields i mean from parent view??

Comment: Not all Fields.I want to hide some fields like Company name,Customer and Function ,priority etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update your xml file,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
<data>
 <!-- ========================This is Form layout===============================-->
<record id="crm_case_form_view_leads_extended" model="ir.ui.view">
<field name="name">CRM - Leads Form</field>
<field name="model">bala.lead</field>
<field name="inherit_id" ref="crm.crm_case_form_view_leads" />
<field name="arch" type="xml">
    <field name="email_from" postion="replace"/>
    <xpath expr="//label[@for='contact_name']" position="before">
                <field name="nitesh_lead"/>
    </xpath>
    <field name="function" position="replace"/>
    <field name="partner_name" position="replace"/>
    <field name="priority" position="replace"/>
    <field name="partner_id" position="replace"/>
</field>
</record>
<record id="new_lead" model="ir.actions.act_window">
  <field name="name">Lead</field>
  <field name="res_model">bala.lead</field>
  <field name="view_type">form</field>
  <field name="view_mode">form</field>
  <field name="view_id" ref="crm_case_form_view_leads_extended"/>
</record>
<!-- ===========================Menu Settings=========================== -->
<menuitem name ="Lead" id = "menu_lis_lab" action="new_lead"/>
</data>
</openerp>
```

you py file should be,

```
from openerp.osv import fields, osv

class crm_lead(osv.osv):
    _name = 'bala.lead'
    _inherit = 'crm.lead'
    _description = "adding fields to crm.lead"
    _columns = {
          'nitesh_lead': fields.char('Nitesh Lead',size=64)
    }
crm_lead()
```

Hope this will give you desired output. and don't forget to update your module after this changes.
[image: Check this]

Comment: Have you tried this. this is not your code. check model in both code mine and yours. both are different which matters a lot. so try this.     <field name="model">bala.lead</field>

Comment: @ Mansi i'm sorry.I couldn't find that diff.I tried your code, it didn't work for me.I'm to create a new field "nitesh_lead"in my lead.py file,it is also no being created in the database

Comment: reason you misspelled _coloumns in your py file. it should be _columns

Comment: your __openerp__.py is also wrong. 'init_xml': ['lead_view.xml'],
'update_xml': [ ],
'demo_xml': [ ], remove this, instead use 'data': ['lead_view.xml'],
'demo':[ ] , what you have used was in previous version of OpenERP. so update that also.

Comment: Sorry to say i modified all the changes you have told me and i tried but it is not working

Comment: @ Mansi Thank's alot.You really saved my day.I have been working for this for couple of days.Can u please provide me a link ,Where i can learn Openerp.Once again Thank's alot

Comment: http://openerp-server.readthedocs.org/en/latest/03_module_dev_03.html
and doc.openerp.com

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46720/discussion-between-nitesh-and-mansi)

Comment: @ Mansi If i want to put contact name field first and then address field,What should i do?I tried like this "<xpath expr="//label[@for='street']" position="before">
                <field name="contact_name"/>
    </xpath>" , but then i'm getting two Contact Name fields.How to remove other "contact_name" field.

Comment: before your code, i mean this xpath, put this <field name="contact_name" position="replace"/>, now you will be able to see only once.