# Removing the accounting tab (page) on Partner form

Tags: forms, customization, odoo, accounting

I've tried to eliminate the Accounting tab on Partner, yet I wasn't able to "hide" the Accounting tab. Is there a specific file in which I should use the following code (or similar):

```
        <page string="Sales & Purchases" position="attributes">
            <attribute name='invisible'>1</attribute> 
        </page>
```

I'm trying to put this into partner_view.xml in accounting. I'm disoriented, and would appreciate any help on this.

thanks a lot in advance. 
Matias

Answer (score 0):

Never do changes in main addons modules. Better create custom module. and inherit `base.view_patner_form` and add this in your xml,

```
    <xpath expr="//page[@string='Accounting']" position="attributes">
        <attribute name='invisible'>True</attribute> 
    </xpath>
```

For your reference, If you want to know how to create custom module, then check this, [After inheriting CRM-Lead unable to hide or add fields to my Custom module in Openerp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21527899/after-inheriting-crm-lead-unable-to-hide-or-add-fields-to-my-custom-module-in-op/21528185#21528185)

Hope this will help you.